# Matlab Median Filter Code

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, filter, median

I am required to implement median filtering in MATLAB for images. However, I'm **not allowed** to use the `medfilt2` or `ordfilt2` functions in MATLAB.  We also have recently started learning MATLAB.

Is there any code available for the median filter or Gaussian filter available?

Comment: Are you allowed to use `nfilter`?

Comment: @CapeCode sounds like homework, so probably not...gotta love those give me teh coodz questions....but I'm guilty and write an answer. Oops. It was more for flexing my coding muscles more than anything

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**NB:** This assumes that the Image Processing Toolbox is installed.

---

The basic premise behind median filtering is to analyze pixel neighbourhoods in your image, sort their intensities, then choose the middle intensity as the result.  One suggestion I can make is to use [`im2col`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/im2col.html) to transform each pixel neighbourhood into a single **column** vector and take all of these column vectors to create a single matrix.  Each column would represent pixel intensities within a pixel neighbourhood.  Next, use [`sort`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/sort.html) and sort along the rows for each column, then grab the **middle** of this sorted matrix which represents the middle value for each pixel neighbourhood.  This will be a single row vector that represents the median value of each pixel neighbourhood.  Once you're done, simply reshape this vector back into the same size as the original image to get your median filtered result.  You can use [`col2im`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/col2im.html) to help facilitate this last step.

However, with `im2col`, it only grabs pixel neighbourhoods that are within the bounds of the original image.  Because you'll want to median filter pixels along the borders of the image, you'll need to **pad** the image borders before processing with `im2col`.  Use [`padarray`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/padarray.html) to do this for you.  I'm going to assume that the border gets padded with zeroes to make things simpler.

Therefore, given a **grayscale** image `im`, and a symmetric neighbourhood to analyze that's `N x N`, where `N` is the width/height of your neighbourhood, your code may look something like this.  I'm also going to assume that `N` is odd to allow picking the median to be easier:

```
im_pad = padarray(im, [floor(N/2) floor(N/2)]);
im_col = im2col(im_pad, [N N], 'sliding');
sorted_cols = sort(im_col, 1, 'ascend');
med_vector = sorted_cols(floor(N*N/2) + 1, :);
out = col2im(med_vector, [N N], size(im_pad), 'sliding');
```

---

Let's do an example.  Let's say our filter size was `5 x 5`, and we'll use `cameraman.tif` that's part of the Image Processing Toolbox.  If we perform the code below then run the median filter code just seen above:

```
N = 5;
im = imread('cameraman.tif');
```

We get the following, with the original image, and the final image that's filtered with median filtering.

[image]

[image]

This is what we expect as median filtering is expected to (more or less) keep the edges well maintained while doing image smoothing.  Median filtering is particularly useful for salt-and-pepper noise where it is highly probable that these noisy pixels will appear the beginning and at the end when sorting pixel neighbourhoods, so choosing the middle value will most likely filter out these noisy values.

---

## Bonus

Your post also is asking to find code from first principles for doing Gaussian filtering.  I answered this a couple of days ago for someone else.

Check this post here: [How do I create and apply a Gaussian filter in MATLAB without using fspecial, imfilter or conv2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27499057/how-to-create-and-apply-a-gaussian-filter-in-matlab-without-using-fspecial-or-im)

Answer (score 2):

I have written a code, it might help:

reading the image and adding noise to it:

```
I=imread('cameraman.tif');
if(size(I,3)~=1)
I=rgb2gray(I);
end
rr=0.1;  
h=imnoise(I,'salt & pepper',rr);
imshow(h);
[M,N]=size(h);
new=h-h;
```

asking the size of the kernel you need:

```
disp('***************Note:zero-padding method is used!***********');
disp('                                                           ');
kernel_size=input('enter the size of the kernel for the Median-ranking? 3 or 5 or 7 or 9=  ');
k=zeros(kernel_size);  %k is the kernel used.
```

applying the median filter to the image:

```
start=kernel_size-floor(kernel_size*0.5);
for x=start:1:M-floor(kernel_size*0.5)
for y=start:1:N-floor(kernel_size*0.5)

%defining x1 & y1 as the 1st coordinates in the kernel
x1=x-(floor(kernel_size*0.5));
y1=y-(floor(kernel_size*0.5));

%specifying image pixels to the kernel
for p=1:1:kernel_size
for q=1:1:kernel_size
 k(p,q)=h(x1+p-1,y1+q-1);
end    
end
d=reshape(k,1,[]);  %k values into an array d 
[r,c]=size(d);
%*****Ordering kernel members***************
for j=1:1:c-1
for i=1:1:c-1
    a=d(1,i);
    b=d(1,i+1);
    if(a>b)
     d(1,i)=b;
     d(1,i+1)=a;
    end
end  
end
Median=d(1,floor(kernel_size*kernel_size*0.5)+1);
  %*****************end of ordering***********
  %*******************************************

   new(x,y)=Median;    
end
end
```

displaying the result:

```
figure;imshow(new,[]);
```

Answer (score 1):

***I am telling you how to start your task.*** All you need is to built up a [sorting algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm) and then pick up the center value. Big portion is implementing the sorting algorithm. Some of them:

- Bucket sort
- List item
- Bubble sort
- Insertion sort
- Selection sort
- Heapsort
- Mergesort

They are not hard to understand and write your own. You can find easily already written. Type to your search engine `sorting algorithms matlab`. You said `I'm looking for the code of the Built-in function of median filter in Matlab.` Matlab allows to seen source code of `meddilt2()` and `ordfilt2()`, you can see the code of these functions, but remember copyright rules.

After implementing the sorting algorithm, you can easily pick the center value of your filter mask by writing `mask( ( numel(mask) + 1 ) / 2 )`.

That' s it.

If you were looking for someone to write the whole solution for your task from scratch, you would have tough work.

Good luck.

---

There are two MATLAB built in function for median filtering: `medfilt2()` and `ordfilt2()`. Actually `medfilt2()` calls `ordfilt2()` in its body. Because median filtering is special case of rank order filtering.

Comment: I know those functions, but I need the code for the median filter or at least the algorithm

Comment: @mehmet - I wrote one from scratch, but I didn't have to do much work.  It was simply a modification of a previous post I did, but the additional requirement is to sort the intensities and choosing the middle.  I probably shouldn't have written an answer, but I did it mainly as a mental exercise above anything else.

Comment: @rayryeng - No problem, it is ok ;)

Answer (score -1):

Here is the code I've written myself. I hope it works.

```
clc;
clear all;
close all;

A=imread('2.jpg');
A=rgb2gray(A);
figure;imshow(A);
Y=imnoise(A,'salt & pepper',0.5);
figure;imshow(Y);
[n,m]=size(A);
%median filter
for i=1:n
   for j=1:m
        mat=zeros(3,3);
        if((i-1) == 0 && (j-1) ~= 0 && j~=m)
            mat(2:3,1:3)=Y(i:i+1,j-1:j+1);
            mat=sort(mat,1);
            mat=sort(mat,2);
            Y(i,j)=mat(2,2);
       elseif(i==n && (j-1)~=0 && j~=m)
            mat(1:2,:)=Y(i-1:i,j-1:j+1);
            mat=sort(mat,1);
            mat=sort(mat,2);
            Y(i,j)=mat(2,2);
       elseif((i-1)~=0 &&(j-1)~=0 && j~=m && i~=n)
            mat(:,:)=Y(i-1:i+1,j-1:j+1);
            mat=sort(mat,1);
            mat=sort(mat,2);
            Y(i,j)=mat(2,2);
        elseif((j-1)==0 && (i-1)~=0 && i~=n)
            mat(:,2:3)=Y(i-1:i+1,j:j+1);
            mat=sort(mat,1);
            mat=sort(mat,2);
            Y(i,j)=mat(2,2);
        elseif(j==m && (i-1)~=0 && i~=n)
            mat(:,1:2)=Y(i-1:i+1,j-1:j);
            mat=sort(mat,1);
            mat=sort(mat,2);
            Y(i,j)=mat(2,2);
        end
    end
end

figure;
imshow(Y)
```