# How do I denoise a simple grayscale image

Tags: matlab, image-processing

Here is the original image with better vision: we can see a lot of noise around the main skeleton, the circle thing, which I want to remove them, and do not affect the main skeleton. I'm not sure if it called noise

I'm doing it to deblurring a image, and this image is the motion blur kernel which identify the camera motion when the camera capture a image.

ps: this image is the kernel for one case, and what I need is a general method in here. thank you for your help

there is a paper in CVPR2014 named "Separable Kernel for Image Deblurring" which talk about this, I want to extract main skeleton of the image to make the kernel more robust, sorry for the explaination here as my English is not good

[image]

and here is the ture grayscale image:

[image]

I want it to be like this:

[image]

How can I do it using Matlab?

here are some other kernel images:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: add other tag for retrieve this question

Comment: BTW, this is not a binary image.  This is actually grayscale.   You can see the varying shades of gray between both images.  Binary should only show black and white intensities.

Comment: Those images are too small.  How can we visually assess the correct results with those images?  I'm voting to close your question.  Too broad... and you keep missing information.

Answer (score 2):

As **@rayryeng** well explained, median filtering is the best option to clean noise in the image, which I realized when I had studied about image restoration. However, in your case, what you need to do seems to me not cleaning noise in the image. You want to more likely eliminate the sparks in the image.

Simply I applied single thresholding to your noisy image to eliminate sparks.

**Try this:**

```
desIm     = imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/jyYUx.png');  % // Your expected (desired) image
nIm       = imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/pXO0p.png');  % // Your original image
nImgray   = rgb2gray(nIm); 
T         = graythresh(nImgray)*255; % // Thereshold value
S         = size(nImgray);
R         = zeros(S) + 5;            % // Your expected image bluish so I try to close it
G         = zeros(S) + 3;            % // Your expected image bluish so I try to close it
B         = zeros(S) + 20;           % // Your expected image bluish so I try to close it
logInd    = nImgray > T;             % // Logical index of pixel exclude spark component
R(logInd) = nImgray(logInd);         % // Get original pixels without sparks
G(logInd) = nImgray(logInd);         % // Get original pixels without sparks
B(logInd) = nImgray(logInd);         % // Get original pixels without sparks
rgbImage  = cat(3, R, G, B);         % // Concatenating Red Green Blue channels
figure,
subplot(1, 3, 1)
imshow(nIm); title('Original Image');
subplot(1, 3, 2)
imshow(desIm); title('Desired Image');
subplot(1, 3, 3)
imshow(uint8(rgbImage)); title('Restoration Result');
```

**What I got is:**
[image]

Comment: Thresholding seems a better fit here. However for efficiency I'd simply do `R(nImR > T) = nImR(nImR > T)`. Repeat the same for the other channels. Use logical indexing instead of `find` whenever possible. Also, `R` can be initialized as `5*ones(S)` and so on.

Comment: thank you for your answer, I already put a threshold in my code, sorry I haven't make the question clear, I already edit it, the threshold seems work for this kernel image, but do not fit the others, so what I need is a general method, not just adjust the threshold for different image.

Comment: @adlyy - You are welcome. Actually your question still isn't clear. You should add some otherkernel image to know what they look like so someone can find how to make generalized method. Btw, if the only problem is to adjust threshold value automatically, you can do it using graythresh(), check my answer I have edited it..

Comment: thank you, fine, actually my problem is I want to extract the main skeleton of the kernel image to denoise the image. But I went with some skeleton extract code, they don't work well. there is a paper in CVPR2014 which has talk about this, but it doesn't have open source.

Comment: @adlyy - For me, it is hard to understand what the main skeleton of other image is :/ If you give more explanation we can think about solutions..

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I can see that is different between the two images is that there is some quantization noise / error around the perimeter of the object.  This resembles [salt and pepper noise](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt-and-pepper_noise) and the best way to remove that noise is to use [median filtering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_filter).  The median filter basically analyzes local overlapping pixel neighbourhoods in your image, sorts the intensities and chooses the median value as the output for each pixel neighbourhood.  Salt and pepper noise corrupts image pixels by randomly selecting pixels and setting their intensities to either black (pepper) or white (salt).  By employing the median filter, sorting the intensities puts these noisy pixels at the lower and higher ends and by choosing the median, you would get the best intensity that could have possibly been there.

To do median filtering in MATLAB, use the [`medfilt2`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/medfilt2.html) function.  This is assuming you have the Image Processing Toolbox installed.  If you don't, then what I am proposing won't work.  Assuming that you do have it, you would call it in the following way:

```
out = medfilt2(im, [M N]);
```

`im` would be the image loaded in [`imread`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imread.html) and `M` and `N` are the rows and columns of the size of the pixel neighbourhood you want to analyze.  By choosing a 7 x 7 pixel neighbourhood (i.e. `M = N = 7`), and reading your image directly from StackOverflow, this is the result I get:

[image]

Compare this image with your original one:

[image]

If you also look at your desired output, this more or less mimics what you want.

Also, the code I used was the following... only three lines!

```
im = rgb2gray(imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/pXO0p.png'));
out = medfilt2(im, [7 7]);
imshow(out);
```

The first line I had to convert your image into grayscale because the original image was in fact RGB.  I had to use [`rgb2gray`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rgb2gray.html) to do that.  The second line performs median filtering on your image with a 7 x 7 neighbourhood and the final line shows the image in a separate window with [`imshow`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imshow.html).

---

## Want to implement median filtering yourself?

If you want to get an idea of how to actually write a median filtering algorithm yourself, check out my recent post here.  A question poser asked to implement the filtering mechanism without using `medfilt2`, and I provided an answer.

[Matlab Median Filter Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27535535/matlab-median-filter-code/27536642#27536642)

---

Hope this helps.

Good luck!

Comment: thank you for your answer which is very detailed, although it's not what I want which is I don't want affact the main skeleton of the image, the circle part, but you offer a very nice idea, I will add in my code and see if it works. thank you again.

Comment: Great explanation as always

Comment: @adlyy you didn't make that very clear in your post. Edit your question to reflect this. FWIW you received negative votes because what you're asking isn't clear.