# Median filter binary image with 3x3 mask in Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I am trying to use the [medfilt2 function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/medfilt2.html) on a 2D binary image with a given 3x3 mask.

unfortunately, medfilt2 does not take a mask as a parameter.

How is it otherwise possible to [median filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_filter) an image with a 3x3 mask ?

for example :

```
binary_image = [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0;
                0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0;
                0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0;
                0 1 0 1 1 1 0 0;
                0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0;
                0 1 1 1 0 1 1 0;
                0 1 0 1 1 1 1 0;
                0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0];

mask = [1 0 1;
        0 1 1 ;
        1 1 1];
```

Comment: Could you implement a median filter yourself and add the mask functionality? It shouldn't be too difficult.

Comment: So do you want to compute the median of only those values that are valid in the `mask`?

Comment: yes rayryeng. eigenchris, i am searching for a built-in method in matlab

Comment: @James - You can use `nlfilter` and specify a custom function that operates on the neighbourhood.  I'll write an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is you can use [`nlfilter`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/nlfilter.html) where you can specify what is done on pixel neighbourhoods in your image.  Specifically, you would call `nlfilter` like so:

```
B = nlfilter(A, [m n], fun);
```

`A` would be an image, `[m n]` would specify the size of the pixel neighbourhoods you're considering (`m x n`), and `fun` is a function that is applied to each neighbourhood.  The input is a `m x n` patch, and the output should be a single value.  Assuming that `mask` is `logical`, and your image is stored in `im`, all you have to do is:

```
out = nlfilter(im, size(mask), @(x) median(x(mask)));
```

`x(mask)` accesses those locations that are valid within the neighbourhood, and you would then apply `median` to these values to retrieve the median value for each neighbourhood over the valid locations.

However, `nlfilter` is known to be slow.  I would recommend you look at my post here: [Matlab Median Filter Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27535535/matlab-median-filter-code/27536642#27536642) .

This computes the `median` filter from first principles very fast.  I will leave it to you to read through the post and understand what I did.  However, what you would have to do to modify this for your purposes is to remove those rows in the output of `im2col` that correspond to invalid values in the mask.  As such, do something like this:

```
N = size(mask,1); %// Size of mask - Assume that # of rows = # of columns
im_pad = padarray(im, [floor(N/2) floor(N/2)]);
im_col = im2col(im_pad, [N N], 'sliding');

%// Get locations in mask that don't count towards getting median
invalid_rows = ~(mask(:));

%// Remove from column neighbourhood matrix
im_col(invalid_rows,:) = [];

%// Determine new median index
val = floor((N*N - sum(invalid_rows))/2) + 1;

%// apply algorithm as normal
sorted_cols = sort(im_col, 1, 'ascend');
med_vector = sorted_cols(val, :);
out = col2im(med_vector, [N N], size(im_pad), 'sliding');
```

`invalid_rows` unrolls the mask into a single column, much like what `im2col` does for each pixel neighbourhood, and then we invert the mask to determine those locations that should not count towards the final median.  Also, `val` determines the **new** index of where we need to obtain the median from once we start removing pixels in neighbourhoods that are not analyzed.

---

If the input is a binary image, then eigenchris's answer to you should be very fast and much faster than what I have written.  However, if this is applied to grayscale images, then what I have written will work.  This works on both binary and grayscale images.

Comment: Nice quick median filter implementation. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you're only dealing with binary images, you can get around this problem by performing convolution with the `conv2()` function.

The logic is that, since you have 7 valid pixels in your mask, if a pixel in the convolution result has a value greater than or equal to 4, we know the median is `1`. Otherwise the median must be `0`.

In general, if you have `n` valid pixels in your mask, we can get the masked median by rounding the result of the convolution matrix divided by `n`.

```
n = sum(sum(mask));                 % number of valid pixels in the mask
maskFlipped = fliplr(flipud(mask)); % flip mask so it faces the right way
convResult = conv2(binary_image,maskFlipped,'same');
maskedMedianFilterResult = round(convResult/n);
```

Comment: Great answer.  You can also achieve the flipping using `maskFlipped = mask(end:-1:1, end:-1:1);`.  This way, we can avoid using two nested function calls.  +1 btw.