# Strange behavior when gaussian blurring an image using big radius / standard deviation

Tags: algorithm, matlab, image-processing, convolution, gaussianblur

**See EDIT**

I tried to implement the gaussian blur algorithm on my own in MATLAB instead of using the built-in algorithm for reasons of understanding it in detail.

I found an [interesting implementation](https://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/81689#answer_91416) and someone has already asked [how to code that kind of algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27499057/how-do-i-create-and-apply-a-gaussian-filter-in-matlab-without-using-fspecial-im). So that is not the business.

Furthermore I use the following formula to calculate the standard deviation of given radius like [GIMP](http://gimpforums.com/thread-standard-deviation-for-gaussian-blur) does:

```
stdDeviation = sqrt(-(radius^2) / (2*log10(1 / 255)));
```

My algorithm works for small values of radius (e.g. 3,5,7) without any problems (you are not able to see the difference at least). If I try to blur an image with the radius of 21, the output is the following:

[image: My result]

Compared to GIMP´s / MATLAB´s `imgaussfilt(A,sigma)` output:

[image: Matlab´s / GIMP´s result]

Obviously the algorithms compute not the same (or at least similar) output image. What does GIMP / MATLAB´s `imgaussfilt(A,sigma)` do apart from that?

The image´s border can be neglected. I'm aware of that problem. But I do not understand the origin of the **'strange pixel stripes'** in my output image.

For reasons of completeness, here is the source code:

```
function y = gaussianBlurSepTest(inputImage)
% radius in pixel; RADIUS MUST BE ODD! 
radius = 21;
% approximate value for standard deviation
stdDeviation = sqrt(-(radius^2) / (2*log10(1 / 255)));

ind = -floor(radius/2):floor(radius/2);
[X, Y] = meshgrid(ind, ind);
h = exp(-(X.^2 + Y.^2) / (2*stdDeviation*stdDeviation));
h = h / sum(h(:));

redChannel = inputImage(:,:,1);
greenChannel = inputImage(:,:,2);
blueChannel = inputImage(:,:,3);

redBlurred = conv2(redChannel, h);
greenBlurred = conv2(greenChannel, h);
blueBlurred = conv2(blueChannel, h);

y = cat(3, uint8(redBlurred), uint8(greenBlurred), uint8(blueBlurred));
```

**EDIT:**

For the sake of completeness and to help others: I applied erfan´s modifications. The result is much better now, but one can still see an obvious difference to gimp´s calculations. GIMP´s result looks 'smoother'.

The implemented algorithm:

```
function y = gaussianBlurSepTest(inputImage)
radius = 21;
stdDeviation = sqrt(-(radius^2) / (2*log10(1 / 255)));
ind = -floor(radius/2):floor(radius/2);
[X, Y] = meshgrid(ind, ind);
[~, R] = cart2pol(X, Y);  % Here R is defined
h = exp(-R.^2 / (2*stdDeviation*stdDeviation));
h = h / sum(h(:));
h(R > radius/2) = 0;
h = h / sum(h(:));
redChannel = inputImage(:,:,1);
greenChannel = inputImage(:,:,2);
blueChannel = inputImage(:,:,3);
redBlurred = conv2(redChannel, h);
greenBlurred = conv2(greenChannel, h);
blueBlurred = conv2(blueChannel, h);
y = cat(3, uint8(redBlurred), uint8(greenBlurred), uint8(blueBlurred));
```

The result:
[image: The implemented algorithm]

GIMP´s result:
[image: GIMP]

In terms of answering the question completely and to help others with the same question I think it might be useful to ask for the origin of the differences.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`h` is responsible for the appeared *horizontal and vertical stripes*. Although you have defined `h` with angular symmetry, as seen in the following plot, its boundaries break this symmetry:

[image: h]

To make things right, you can truncate `h` on the correct radius:

[image: truncated h]

I applied the modification to your function and now it should give much better results:

```
function y = gaussianBlurSepTest(inputImage, radius)
stdDeviation = sqrt(-(radius^2) / (2*log10(1 / 255)));
ind = -floor(radius/2):floor(radius/2);
[X, Y] = meshgrid(ind, ind);
[~, R] = cart2pol(X, Y);  % Here R is defined
h = exp(-R.^2 / (2*stdDeviation*stdDeviation));
h = h / sum(h(:));
h(R > radius/2) = 0;  % And here h is truncated. The rest is the same.
```

Here is my test. My image:

[image]

After your `gaussianBlurSepTest` (radius = 35):

[image]

After the modified function:

[image]

**Note:** The output gets darker a bit. If it is an issue, you can re-normalize `stdDeviation` or widen your meshgrid.

Comment: I understand my mistake now. Thank you! That will do the job for me! I´ll mark the answer as accecpted. 
For the sake of completeness and to help others I think it is useful to ask how one can improve the algorithm apart from that. See my edit.

Comment: I believe with increasing the size of your mesh (and therefore increasing the range of `h`) you could get much better results. But with the cost of much more computation time. Try it with doubling the range of the meshgrid.

Answer (score 0):

I think the culprit is `conv2` instruction and it is because your image type is `uint8` or `uint16`, when you are filtering your image you should use `float` or `double` type. 
Your filter size is so high, that the resultant of application of coefficients window on pixels exceeds 8 bits or 16 bits integer range (255 or 65535). I suggest to try to cast your image to `double` before application of your filter and after the application of the filter cast it back to `uint8` as below:

```
   Output=gaussianBlurSepTest(double(inputImage));
   Output=uint8(Output);
```

Good luck.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Unfortunately your suggestion does not influence the output image in any way.